# Ruby on Rails Views not working even when blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app that had a few views working.  I made some changes that I cannot revert easily (I know, big mistake, mainly to the views though). I believe I am following Rails folder structure conventions correctly because the views WERE working. Now, when I try to see ANY view in the browser, I get the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/instance_controller.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

I am not calling each in either of application_controller or instance_controller.  instance_controller is the controller related to the view I am trying to render.  If I use a different view, I will see a different controller in the error message instead of instance_controller.  Application_controller is the parent of instance_controller. Even changing to an empty view with just some plain text or JSON will produce the same error. Is there some underlying Rails stuff happening that I have, perhaps overridden or something? Still really new to MVC and Rails in general. Even if you can't give me the exact answer, but perhaps a list of things to check over, anything helps.

application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

instance_controller:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'
include HTTParty
class InstanceController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tab = 'instance'
    @server_list = Server.get_server_list()
    @instances = ::ServerList.get_instances_on_all_servers
  end

  def self.update_credentials

    Rails.logger.info(params.to_s)
    in__hash = {
      <some parameters>
    }

    response = put(
              <some_path_I_can't_post>
              )
  end


end
```

EDIT: Additional info requested, config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :server
  resources :instance
end
```

Output from running  rake routes :

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
server_index GET    /server(.:format)            server#index
            POST   /server(.:format)            server#create
 new_server GET    /server/new(.:format)        server#new
edit_server GET    /server/:id/edit(.:format)   server#edit
     server GET    /server/:id(.:format)        server#show
            PATCH  /server/:id(.:format)        server#update
            PUT    /server/:id(.:format)        server#update
            DELETE /server/:id(.:format)        server#destroy
instance_index GET    /instance(.:format)          instance#index
           POST   /instance(.:format)          instance#create
new_instance GET    /instance/new(.:format)      instance#new
edit_instance GET    /instance/:id/edit(.:format) instance#edit
  instance GET    /instance/:id(.:format)      instance#show
           PATCH  /instance/:id(.:format)      instance#update
           PUT    /instance/:id(.:format)      instance#update
           DELETE /instance/:id(.:format)      instance#destroy
```

And we have app/controllers/instance_controller.rb, and 
app/controllers/application_controller.rb for paths.

EDIT 2 (Solved): 
I have been using unicorn_rails to deploy my website. I am not sure why, but I think my unicorn server was timing out at every request. restarting the server process removed these errors.

Comment: ActionController::RoutingError --> Post the relevant routes in config/routes.rb as well as the folder structure you have for this particular controller.

Comment: I posted the information you requested.

Comment: If I had to guess I would say it's something with the naming of one of your folders or directories (M,V, or C) for `instance`. Did you manually rename anything at one point or have some pluralization somewhere by accident? Those `ActionController::RoutingError` errors usually mean the route isn't finding the correct view or controller. Also check that the classnames are correct and match up with the filenames.

Comment: After triple checking everything, I decided to restart Unicorn server and all the errors disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that you are calling `each` on either @server_list or @instances within the index view and possibly one of those instance variables is `nil`.

If so, you should wrap your `each` block in an `if` statement like so:

```html
<% if @instances %>
  <% @instances.each do |instance| %>
    .....
    do your thing here...
    .....
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You can also call `to_a` on a variable which will return an empty array instead of nil if the variable is nil.

```html
<% @instances.to_a.each do |instance| %>
  .....
  do your thing here...
  .....
<% end %>
```

Comment: This was my first thought when I saw that .each was being called on a nil variable. However, doing the above and even removing all the calls to .each in the view, (Even just making the view a blank page or some generic JSON/HTML) is causing the same error.  It is like something within Rails framework is calling each?